# Java find html tag

Tags: java, html

Hi I am trying to delete an HTML tag from a string.
The tag I am trying to delete is

```
<td class="gutter"> text text </td>
```

I tried the following but nothing worked:

```
String regex = "<td class=\"gutter\">([^<]*)</td>";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(htmlstring);
m.find() / m.matches()
```

But cant seem to find it at all... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _Sigh..._ Use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to strip tags from HTML, use a library that does that.  Don't roll your own HTML parser.

```
<plug shameless="true">
```

http://code.google.com/p/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/

> A fast and easy to configure HTML Sanitizer written in Java which lets you include HTML authored by third-parties in your web application while protecting against XSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use regular expressions to work with HTML (or XML). It is impossible to do it right (not "hard", but technically impossible). Use a HTML parser like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org). Then it is easy, just follow the docs.